# Why does my HTC Desire play a tune (like notification) without a visual message?

Tags: htc-desire, notifications

A friend of mine has a HTC Desire and every so often it play a little tune (like a message notification) even though there are no messages or calls. What's causing this?

Comment: Do any application icons appear in the notification bar (the top-left corner)?

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by a notification set for a calendar event (or a task, if you have a task organiser that integrates with the calendar). I found that if I dismissed a calendar notification, it would continue to activate but it wouldn't appear in the notification bar! I had to go through my calendar, look for events with notifications, and disable any outstanding ones that I found.